App is not opening directly even when app is installed in Compose Context
fun openAppOrPlayStore(context: Context, packageName: String) {
    val launchIntent = context.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)
    if (launchIntent != null) {
        launchIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        context.startActivity(launchIntent)
    } else {
        val playStoreIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
            data = Uri.parse("market://details?id=$packageName")
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        }
        try {
            context.startActivity(playStoreIntent)
        } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
            // Handle the case where Play Store is not found
            val webPlayStoreIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
                data = Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=$packageName")
                addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            }
            context.startActivity(webPlayStoreIntent)
        }
    }
}

I'm trying to navigate the user to the app directly when app is installed and if app not installed it will take it to playstore to download the app.
But this function take user to playstore every time.


Do you declare the target package in your Manifest? https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring

@JanBína Yes I have declared the target packages. It seems that target application has restriction to launch directly. Because I can launch other apps.
Do you suggest any alternate to launch these type of app directly.

Here is the package declaration, but still it is not working.




</queries>

